# Python click show global option in help text of Sub-Command

Tags: python, python-click

I'm trying to figure out how to get help for global options shown in the help messages of sub-commands.

I created a simplistic cli:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import click


@click.group()
@click.option("-l", "--log-level", help="Set log level.")
def cli(log_level):
    "CLI toolbox"
    print("root")


@cli.group()
def admin():
    print("admin")


@admin.command()
def invite():
    print("invite")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Unfortunately the global options are not shown on the help screens of sub commands:

```
./cli.py --help
Usage: cli.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  CLI toolbox

Options:
  -l, --log-level TEXT  Set log level. <-- Option listed on global command
  --help                Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  admin
```

```
./cli.py admin --help
root
Usage: cli.py admin [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
     <- Option missing on command.
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  invite
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means pretty, but it gets the options by defining a custom group so we can override the help message. It then also iterates through all subcommands, but that has been hardcoded to only reference that particular group, rather than programatically infer it.

```py
import click


@click.group()
@click.option("-l", "--log-level", help="Set log level.")
def cli(log_level):
    "CLI toolbox"
    print("root")


class CustomHelpGroup(click.Group):
    def format_help(self, ctx, formatter):
        parent = ctx.parent
        help_text = ['Greetings! Options:']
        for param in parent.command.get_params(ctx):
            help_text.append(' '.join(param.get_help_record(parent)))
        help_text.append("\n" + ctx.get_usage() + "\n")
        help_text.append('Commands:\n')
        help_text.extend([f'{command_name}' for command_name, command in admin.commands.items()])
        formatter.write('\n'.join(help_text))


@cli.group(cls=CustomHelpGroup)
def admin():
    print("admin")


@admin.command()
def invite():
    print("invite")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```